Conditional formatting comparing cell to cell values in a range
Pic with a table 
Each column is a number of requests by month, so I would like to mark the values that 15% bigger, then in a previous month. (rows are "query name" and not important)
I made a custom formula: =C2>1,15*B2 for the range B2:T and some marks are confusing me. For example, why M2 cell is not marked its 26,5% bigger then L2. Also what's wrong with F2, its smaller then E2, why its marked? Is there some mistake with cell picked for comparison in custom formula?
GS link

Pretty hard to say anything when not knowing the values..... ("what's wrong with F2, its smaller then E2")

Please try to share so much info, that we can reproduce your problem, something like: https://i.sstatic.net/263YJJtM.png  (But, noted, I do not like pictures.... )

Here is the GS link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19IZfmwl7u11t-L-wXATHGl7oFdDEmA1J7gaF9yVX6z4/edit?usp=sharing

It was a pic attached but its gone )))

Please read "Proofread before posting!": https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=Proofread%20before%20posting!

sure. It was there )

From the same document I linked earlier: "Not everyone can access external sites"

Even Google sheets as external site? It's confusing as for me and also, regarding the pics: "Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them". But anyway I've added both. Thank you for your help

Stackoverflow recommended method to share a sample dataset is to create a markdown table. You can use this tool to create the markdown_format & add it to your question in general. Additionally you can also share an image OR a test sheet provided you've already supplied the markdown dataset in your question. There could be scenarios where your question could be flagged and closed off, if you solely provide just the image and/or google sheet

"Also what's wrong with F2, its smaller then E2, why its marked?"  In the picture you added F2 is not marked.....

Yes, sorry, mistype, its e3 vs f3

505498/432404=  1.16    So it matches the formula.  When you always want to compare against column C change the C in the formula to $C .

Change the range setting to C2:T since your custom formula is =C2>1,15*B2
